# jQuery "toggleClass" working only for the first selected option only in the select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a select box each option in the select box contains the same data, a main `ul` with main `li` that contains a sub `ul` that works on click... if i choose an option the on click function works in it by toggling a class... but if i choose another option without refresh the toggle that should be happened by the on click is not happening.

```
$(document).on('click','.main-li', function(){
    var topics = data;
    var sectionId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(select.value);
    $.get('{{ GET_ILOS }}/'+select.value+'/'+sectionId, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function( key, value ) {
            var Input = '<li class="sub-li" data-id="'+value.id+'"  id="btn-li"> "'+value.name+'" </li>';
            $('#sub-'+value.section_id).children().remove();
            $('#sub-'+value.section_id).append(Input);
            Input = '';
        });
    }); 


    $(this).find('.sub-ul').toggleClass('show');
    $(this).siblings().children('ul').removeClass('show') 

});
```

but if i changed this line

```
$(this).find('.sub-ul').toggleClass('show');
```

to

```
$(this).find('.sub-ul').addClass('show');
```

it works well!

how can i make this code work with toggleClass not addClass?

known that the `jQuery` code is working well with `toggleClass` in static mode, but not working when converting code to dynamic

Comment: in the toggleClass you need to define the class in css

Comment: Please share relevant HTML code so that we can help you better